# OS X tags on network shared files don't work

Tags: macos

I would like to use OS X tags on files in a Windows shared network location.  I expect the tags information are saved in the DS_Store file, so I made sure to run in terminal:

`defaults delete com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores`

What happens is I can set the tag, but when I click on the tag in the Finder sidebar, none of the tagged files from the network share show up.

Comment: They're unlikely to be Spotlight indexed on a remote Windows volume. The tags will show when you view the file on the remote volume [unless someone is actively stripping .DS_Store or AppleDouble data], but it won't search.